# How do I set specific columns to be selectable in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, listselectionlistener

How do I ensure that only some of my columns in my JTable are selectable (meaning they route to my ListSelectionListener)?

I have added my listener as follows:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {...});
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: When a column in my JTable is selected I notify a certain set of listeners. However, I have another column in the same table which is an Editor. I don't want to notify the listeners when the user selects the Editor column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution may be to create your own selection model:

```
table.getColumnModel().setSelectionModel(new DefaultListSelectionModel() {
    private boolean isSelectable(int index0, int index1) {
        // TODO: Decide if this column index is selectable
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
        if(isSelectable(index0, index1)) {
            super.setSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
        if(isSelectable(index0, index1)) {
            super.addSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
        }
    }
});
```

Note also that if you want to listen on column selection, you want to add your listener to the column model's selection model (not the table's selection model).